# При попытке преобразовать столбец DataFrame из типа данных Object в тип данных float64 все данные DataFrame принимают значение NaN

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, python-2.7

После чтения из cvs файла

```py
frame = pd.read_csv('Discount.csv', header=0, sep=',')
```

получаю следующий набор данных:
[image: Исходные данные]

Все данные frame на этот момент имеют тип Object:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке преобразовать столбец Selling_TC к типу numeric

```py
frame.Selling_TC = pd.to_numeric(frame.Selling_TC, errors='coerce')
```

ПОЧТИ все данные принимают значения NaN:
[image: Информация по Frame]

Что может быть не так с исходными данными? С остальными столбцами с числовыми данными происходит то же самое.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавьте пример входных данных в текстовом виде - из CSV скопируйте, например. Под вопросом есть кнопка "править".

Comment: Поставлю вопросу +1, если картинная галерея примет текстовый вид.

Answer (score 3):

Думаю, дело в том, что исходные данные - строки и в них есть недопустимые символы - запятые и пробелы, из-за которых не получается перевести их в числа. Параметр `errors='coerce'` при ошибках конвертирования заменяет значения на `NaN`.

```
In [82]: df 
Out[82]: 
            a           b
0   71 200,00   49 987,75
1  220 811,23  190 660,25

In [83]: df.dtypes 
Out[83]: 
a    object
b    object
dtype: object

In [84]: pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce')
Out[84]: 
0   NaN
1   NaN
Name: a, dtype: float64
```

Можно предварительно очистить данные от лишних символов и потом уже перевести в числа. Сделать это можно с помощью [`str.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html). Уберем пробелы и заменим запятые на точки:

```
In [85]: df.a = df.a.str.replace(',', '.').str.replace(' ', '')          

In [86]: df           
Out[86]: 
           a           b
0   71200.00   49 987,75
1  220811.23  190 660,25

In [87]: pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce') 
Out[87]: 
0     71200.00
1    220811.23
Name: a, dtype: float64

In [88]: df.a = pd.to_numeric(df.a, errors='coerce')  

In [89]: df  
Out[89]: 
           a           b
0   71200.00   49 987,75
1  220811.23  190 660,25

In [90]: df.dtypes         
Out[90]: 
a    float64
b     object
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 3):

Проще всего сразу правильно парсить CSV:

```
frame = pd.read_csv('Discount.csv', thousands=' ', decimal=',')
```

Comment: Изначально сработало только для столбца Discount. Для остальных столбцов пришлось сначала менять формат данных в исходном файле. После смены формата получилось.

Comment: @ЛераНикитушкина, лучше всего в таких вопросах выкладывать ссылку на файлообменник (на исходный CSV файл). Тогда есть возможность проверить ответ